# LRUCache BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, image-resizing, bounds, android-lru-cache, bitmapdrawable

I'm using an LruCache to cache a lot of small BitmapDrawables used throughout my app. The problem is that the sizes differ for the different places I use the images.

I set the bounds when I retrieve the drawable from the cache before setting it to the ImageView to have the correct size.

When I set the bounds, the drawable resizes on the other places as well.

How can I get around this issue without using `drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable()`? Creating a new drawable from the cached drawable is very slow when scrolling a listview.

The same images are used in DynamicDrawableSpans where I can't set the bounds on the span itself, only on the drawable directly.

Will it be wise to have the same drawable image cached for the different contexts in seperate Caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work correctly.

I changed the LruCache type from BitmapDrawable to Bitmap. This way the cache only stores the Bitmap image and not the drawable bounds as well.

When I want to set the bitmap I convert it to `BitmapDrawable`

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Then I set the bounds for the newly created drawable instance

```
d.setBounds(0, 0, sizex, sizey);
```

This way each instance of the Bitmap is a seperate `Drawable` with its own Bounds.